# S3 sleep problems -- nVidia or Intel H67 (Sandy Bridge motherboard) issue?

Tags: kernel, suspend

I have a new Sandy Bridge i5-2500 and Intel H67 motherboard. As the onboard video didn't work, I put in an older 8600 gts graphics card. However, the S3 suspend won't work (and I can't test without the dedicated card). I've had this experience with all other desktops (all of which have nvidia cards).

Any help diagnosing what might be the problem would be appreciated. I've been trying a few s2ram parameters at [en.opensuse.org/SDB:Suspend_to_RAM](http://en.opensuse.org/SDB%3aSuspend_to_RAM), but this is very time consuming and so far fruitless. Namely,

- Of course, if you have experience with a H67 or P67 motherboard, that would be most useful.
- If you have owned Intel desktop motherboards, how often does S3 work?
- same with nVidia graphics cards
- Does the power supply ever make a difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to have been fixed now, I'm using OpenSuSE 11.4. My uname string is

```
Linux linux-sdia 2.6.37.6-0.7-desktop #1 SMP PREEMPT 2011-07-21 02:17:24 +0200 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

and the nVidia driver is `275.21`.

Answer (score 1):

I have no issues on my P67 based motherboard ( Asus ) with an ATI card, but a number of people have complained in this [bug](http://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/760842) about having problems with H67.

You might find [this page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingKernelSuspend) useful for help debugging the problem.